# Pysnow Usage of sysparm_query_category

Tags: python, servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

As I cannot see any reference on how to use properly the sysparm_query_category, may I confirm on how did you append the sysparm_query_category in get request?

Added below line of codes. I hope someone can help and guide me as I'm new to ServiceNow. Thanks!

```
from pysnow import Client

...

resource = self.client.resource(api_path=F"/table/{table}")
resource.parameters.add_custom({"sysparm_query_category": "cat_read_generic"})
request = resource.get(query=query, fields=fields)
```

https://developer.servicenow.com/dev.do#!/reference/api/sandiego/rest/c_TableAPI

Comment: can you briefly explain what exactly you are trying to achieve? For example, trying to retrieve data from a table with a filter so and so. That would help in answering your question.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware `pysnow` API. I hope this helps. Else refer to the comment above.

```
#Need to install requests package for python
#easy_install requests
import requests

# Set the request parameters
url = 'https://demonightlycoe.service-now.com/api/now/table/incident?sysparm_query=category%3Dcat_read_generic&sysparm_limit=1'

# Eg. User name="admin", Password="admin" for this code sample.
user = 'admin'
pwd = 'admin'

# Set proper headers
headers = {"Content-Type":"application/json","Accept":"application/json"}

# Do the HTTP request
response = requests.get(url, auth=(user, pwd), headers=headers )

# Check for HTTP codes other than 200
if response.status_code != 200: 
    print('Status:', response.status_code, 'Headers:', response.headers, 'Error Response:',response.json())
    exit()

# Decode the JSON response into a dictionary and use the data
data = response.json()
print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Upon checking and testing, we can use the add_custom

```
client.parameters.add_custom({'foo': 'bar'})
```

that would be additional to the parameters like &foo=bar
https://pysnow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/parameters.html